# is it safe to run yum remove '*.i386' on a 64bit Centos System?

Tags: yum, centos5, i386, x86-64

I just want to know if it would be safe to remove all 386 packages from my x86_64 system? Are any of the 386 packages actually used or do they just sit there?

The reason i'd like to remove them, is often with updates, there is a clash due to conflicting i386 packages, so removing them would also feel tidier if the system doesn't need them.

thank in advance.

Shadi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's safe - typically they either got installed at the beginning or some errant install down the line sucked them in as dependencies. When you do the yum remove do not include a -y on it, and carefully examine the list of packages to ensure you're not erasing something you obviously want.

```
rpm -qa --queryformat='%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n' | grep '\.i[3456]86$' | sort
```

That will give you a list of packages to just examine without doing anything.

Comment: There are a lot of packages i do want, but are they actually functional or is their x86_64 counterpart the functional one?

Comment: *Typically*, on a standard x86_64 system, their 64bit counterpart is the active one. This is not 100% written in stone as you may have a package which requires a 32bit library in order to function; as your personal system is unique there is no one exact answer for you. If you do the yum remove to test, cast a critical eye on what's being removed - dependencies, utilities and the like and let your spidey sense guide you. You should be able to remove a lot of those .?86 packages without any problems, though - even if you do have to keep some of them, most are probably clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, there's a [CentOS wiki page](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-357346ff0bf7c14b0849c3bcce39677aaca528e9) that tackles this exactly, with tips on how to avoid those packages being installed in the future.  Keep in mind, though, like @troyengel mentioned earlier, there are likely packages on your system that **do** need the 32-bit version installed.